# Docker network configuration endpoints

Tags: docker, docker-compose, frontend, backend, docker-network

I want to know how to configure correctly the backend endpoint.

I have a docker images that runs different containers:

- Backend
- Frontend
- Nginx for backend
- DB

From my understanding, since all containers are running on the same machine, I should be able to reach the backend with "host.docker.internal".

Indeed I can successfully do it on the local machine where Docker is running on.

By the way the frontend is not able to resolve the endpoint "host.docker.internal" if I try to make a request from another machine. Please note that I'm able to reach the frontend from another machine, it's just a matter of endpoint configuration.

[image]

Note that "192.168.1.11" is the IP of the machine where Docker is running, and "8888" it's the port where the frontend is.

Obviously I can succesfully make the requests from other machines too if I put the static IP address instead of "host.docker.internal". But the question is: since the React frontend application is served on Docker itself, shouldn't it be able to resolve the "host.docker.internal" endpoint?

Just for reference, here it is my docker compose:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db: #mysqldb
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: ${DB_SERVICE_NAME}
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    ports:
      - $MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - backend

  mrmfrontend:
    build:
      context: ./mrmfrontend
      args:
        - REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=$CLIENT_API_BASE_URL
        - REACT_APP_BACKEND_ENDPOINT=$REACT_APP_BACKEND_ENDPOINT
        - REACT_APP_FRONTEND_ENDPOINT=$REACT_APP_FRONTEND_ENDPOINT
        - REACT_APP_FRONTEND_ENDPOINT_ERROR=$REACT_APP_FRONTEND_ENDPOINT_ERROR
        - REACT_APP_CUSTOMER=$REACT_APP_CUSTOMER
        - REACT_APP_NAME=$REACT_APP_NAME
        - REACT_APP_OWNER=""
    ports:
      - $REACT_LOCAL_PORT:$REACT_DOCKER_PORT
    networks:
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose/nginx/frontend:/etc/nginx/conf.d/

  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: admin
        uid: 1000
      context: ./MRMBackend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: backend
    container_name: backend-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./MRMBackend:/var/www
    networks:
      - backend

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: backend-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./MRMBackend:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx/backend:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend

volumes:
  db:

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

The endpoint is configured in this way in the .env:

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_ENDPOINT="http://host.docker.internal:8000"
```

Comment: The React application runs in your browser, not a container, and can't use any of the Docker-internal hostnames or networking.  The best way to do this is to set up your Nginx reverse proxy to proxy both the application and the backend, and set the backend URL to a path-only URL like `/api`.  The browser will interpret this as "the same host and port as the current page" and this problem goes away.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your clarification. Just one more question: the proxy should be done by the frontend Nginx or backend Nginx?

Comment: Combine those into one Nginx.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your explanation. I'm going to configure a single Nginx and use the reverse proxy. If you put your comment as answer I'll accept it